# How redirect to login page if principal is null in spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I use spring security to provide authentification. Here is my spring-security.xml:

```
<beans:beans>
    <http auto-config="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/user/*" access="ROLE_USER" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/admin/*" access="ROLE_ADMIN" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/recipe/*" access="ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_USER" />
        <form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/welcome"
                    authentication-failure-url="/loginfailed" />
        <logout logout-success-url="/logout" />
    </http>

    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider ref="customAuthenticationProvider"/>
    </authentication-manager>

    <beans:bean id="customAuthenticationProvider" class="CustomAuthenticationProvider"/>
</beans:beans>
```

If user doesn't work for a long time inside /recipe url, then here

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/recipe/new", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView addRecipePost(final Principal principal, final @ModelAttribute RecipeForm)
```

i receieve principal = null. I wish user was redirected to the login screen. Is it possible? How can I do that?

Comment: Well ... what you ask for is just the default behaviour of Spring security ! The good question is why it does not work with your config ... Maybe you could try to write `intercept-url pattern="/recipe/**" ...` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that some urls were missing inside xml  tag.